# Difficulty parsing JSON with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I wrote the following code:

```
Alamofire.request("\(NSLocalizedString("base_url", comment: ""))\(NSLocalizedString("url_rateCard", comment: ""))").responseJSON{response in
    let status:Int = (response.response?.statusCode)!
    switch status{
    case 200:
        switch response.result{
            case .success(let suc):
                let json = JSON(suc)
                print(json)
                self.rateCardCollectionView.delegate = self
                self.rateCardCollectionView.dataSource = self
                break
        case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                break
        }
        break
    default:
        print("Could not call ratecard api")
        break
    }
}
```

And I am getting this result:

```
{
  "error" : null,
  "data" : [
    {
      "name" : "Air Conditioner 1.5ton",
      "unit" : "piece",
      "_id" : "58d3c7a277d862536fb5ec2e",
      "itemComment" : "Mentioned price is subjected to change on vendor visit.",
      "price" : 1450,
      "icon" : "\/images\/rate-card\/undefined-1490685861277.png"
    },
...
```

Please take a look at the json, specially at the icon field. It should be something like this:

> "icon": "/images/rate-card/undefined-1490685861277.png",

Comment: how can I get the right icon string? Please check my last statement in the question

Comment: am I doing something wrong when I create the JSON object?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet of your Model?

Comment: @EricAya thank you. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is in the first dictionary of the array for key `data`:

```
let json = JSON(suc)
if let icon = json["data"][0]["icon"].string {
    print(icon)
}
```

or if you want to print all `icon`s in the array

```
let json = JSON(suc)
if let data = json["data"].array {
   for item in data {
       if let icon = item["icon"].string {
          print(icon)
       }
   }
}
```